# 10th Anniversary of Expatriates SE!

Tags: discussion, featured

This month (March) Expatriates SE turns 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!

Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.

How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Answer (score 4):

I joined the beta site just a couple months after moving to another country and it became a quite useful resource for me during that time, and ever since. The main benefit is for me however that it opened up my eye to what issues people face all around the world and how it's solved by different countries. It also made me more aware on what to keep an eye out when dealing with both short and long term immigration related issues.

Answer (score 3):

I had been active on an immigration forum that specialized in such topics for the UK, having myself been through some of the processes directly. It was great helping people with honest information, and there were (and still are) wonderful experts there to help out with correct up-to-date information. Unfortunately, there was a caustic pernicious bias against Americans there that slowly drove me away (along with Brexit, which was handled poorly there). I found out about Expats, a considerably more neutral place, to give great advice and possibly make a positive difference in the lives of people - some of whom seeking new lives, even if that advice wasn't always what they wanted hear. I like the ability maintain an objective inclusive repository of knowledge that everybody can benefit from.